# Add Android Widget Project As Library in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libraries

After the new Android SDK update I had some problems configuring the libraries. I was able to implement the Google Play Services library in my project, but I downloaded a 3rd party widget which I just can't implement right - every time an activity using this widget comes up I get the error "NoClassDefFoundError". This is how I added the library:

1. Created a .jar file from the project
2. Added the .jar file to the /libs dir
3. Connected the project to my app (Build path - Configure build path - projects)

I read on some post that when I get this error I need to check if the only library ticked in the "Java Build Path" properties on the "Order And Export" tab is "Android Private Libraries".
I tried to tick the widget project as well but it got me nowhere.

So, how do I implement this library right?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't do step 3, but you should check the order of the items in the build path.

This is the correct order of the items:

- Android 4.3
- Android private libraries
- Android dependencies .
- .../gen
- .../src

Also, if you use third party views , you can drag&drop them via the UI designer, or write the full path to the view itself in XML .